# Loop suspends after first iteration for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, linked-list, shared-ptr, do-while

The following is an implementation of linked list using `shared_ptr`. All the routines invoked from `main()` work as expected, which validates the associated template class method definitions in `code.hpp`,  except for `reverse_menu()` which interfaces with `reverse()` method in the definition of the `list` class template in `code.hpp`.

The source code has been reproduced below for your reference.

```
    //code.hpp

#ifndef CODE_HPP
#define CODE_HPP
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define DBG_TRACE (cout << "At line " << __LINE__ << endl);

template<typename T>
class node{
    private:
        T& data;
        shared_ptr<node<T>> next;
    private:
        void set_data(T&);
    public:
        node(T&);
        ~node();
    public:
        T& get_data(void);
        shared_ptr<node<T>> get_next (void);
        void set_next(shared_ptr<node<T>>);
};

template<typename X>
class list{
    private:
        shared_ptr<X> head;
        list(shared_ptr<X>);
    public:
        shared_ptr<X> get_head(void);
        void set_head(shared_ptr<X>);
    public:
        list();
        ~list();
    public:
        size_t size (void)const;
        shared_ptr<X> operator[] (size_t) const;
        size_t remove (size_t);
        void reverse (void);
};

template<typename T>
node<T>::node(T& _data):data(_data){
    this->next = NULL;
}
template<typename T>
node<T>::~node(){
}

template<typename T>
void node<T>::set_next(shared_ptr<node<T>> next){
    DBG_TRACE
    this->next = next;

    DBG_TRACE
    return;
}
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<node<T>> node<T>::get_next(void){
    return(this->next);
}
template<typename T>
T& node<T>::get_data(void){
    return(this->data);
}

template<typename X>
list<X>::list(){
    this->head = NULL;
}

template<typename X>
list<X>::~list(){
}

template<typename X>
shared_ptr<X> list<X>::get_head(void){
    return(this->head);
}

template<typename X>
void list<X>::set_head(shared_ptr<X> head){
    this->head = head;

    return;
}

template<typename X>
size_t list<X>::size (void)const{
    auto h = this->head;
    auto count = 0;

    while(h->get_next()){
        ++count;
        h = h->get_next();
    }
    if(h && !h->get_next()){
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

template<typename X>
shared_ptr<X> list<X>::operator[] (size_t idx) const{

    if(idx >= this->size()){
        return NULL;
    }

    auto h = this->head;
    size_t count = 0;

    while(h && count < idx){
        ++count;
        h = h->get_next();
    }

    return h;
}

template<typename X>
size_t list<X>::remove(size_t idx){

    if(idx >= this->size()){
        //a workaround; need to 
        //replace with exception
        return (this->size());
    }
    else{

         if(0 == idx){
         auto h = (*this)[idx];
         auto nxt = h->get_next();
         this->set_head(nxt);
         h.reset();
        }
        else{
         auto h = (*this)[idx - 1];
         auto nxt = h->get_next()->get_next();
         h->get_next().reset();
         h->set_next(nxt);
        }

        return (this->size());
   }
}

template<typename X>
void list<X>::reverse(void){
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t sz = size();
    i = sz - 1;
    j = i - 1;

    DBG_TRACE
    cout << "i:" << i << endl;
    cout << "j:" << j << endl;

    do{
        DBG_TRACE
        (*this)[i]->set_next((*this)[j]);
        i = j;
        j = i - 1;
        cout << "i:" << i << endl;
        cout << "j:" << j << endl;
        DBG_TRACE
     }while(j >= 0);

     DBG_TRACE

    set_head((*this)[sz - 1]);
    (*this)[i]->set_next(NULL);

    return;
}
#endif



//main.cpp

#include "code.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

void load_menu(void);
void rectify_menu (void);
void reverse_menu (void);
void print_menu(void);

list<node<string>>menu;
vector<string>menu_items{"pasta", "cake", "pizza", "soup", "muffin", "chai", "pie", "croissant", "coffee"};

int main (void){
    load_menu();
    //print_menu();

    rectify_menu();
    //print_menu();

    reverse_menu();
    print_menu();

    return 0;
}

void load_menu (void){
    auto num_menu_items = menu_items.size();

for(size_t i = 0; i < num_menu_items; ++i){
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            {
                auto menu_item = make_shared<node<string>>(menu_items[i]);
                menu_item->set_next(NULL);
                menu.set_head(menu_item);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            {
                auto menu_item = make_shared<node<string>>(menu_items[i]);
                menu_item->set_next(NULL);

                auto m = menu.get_head();

                while(m->get_next()){
                     m = m->get_next();
                }

                m->set_next(menu_item);
            }
            break;
        default:    
            break;
    }
}

    return;
}

void rectify_menu (void){

    size_t num_menu_items = menu.size(); 
    assert(num_menu_items == menu_items.size()); 
    size_t i = 0;

    do{
        auto item_i = menu[i]->get_data();
        //cout << i <<  " " << "item_i: " << item_i << endl;
        for(size_t j = i + 1; j < num_menu_items; ++ j){
            auto item_j = menu[j]->get_data();
            //cout << j << " " << "item_j: " << item_j << endl;
           if(item_i == item_j){
               num_menu_items = menu.remove(j);
           }
       }
    }while(++i <= num_menu_items - 1); 

    return;
}

void print_menu (void){
    auto h = menu.get_head();
    do{
        cout << h->get_data() << endl;
    }while(h = h->get_next());
    cout << endl;

    return;
}

void reverse_menu (void){
    menu.reverse();

    return;
}
```

In `link<X>::reverse()` and `node<T>::set_next()`, I have included debug print statements to figure out the flow of logic. Below is the output of the program, after disabling the invocation of `print_menu()` twice before the invocation of `reverse_menu()` from `main()` (to view the complete program output please enable the commented out `print_menu()` invocations from `main()`) :

```
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 163
i:8
j:7
At line 168
At line 58
At line 61
i:7
j:6
At line 174
At line 168
```

It is evident from the debug trace that the do-while loop inside `link<X>::reverse()` suspends for no evident reason after the first iteration. This conclusion has been drawn based on the fact that the values of both `i` and `j` are printed once inside the loop, before loop execution stalls. If the program were to be compiled and run, the line numbers included in the debug trace would also confirm this observation.

The following is the gdb output:

```
$ gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 8.1.1-1) 8.1.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.exe...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/Vin/coding_practice/cpp/google/ctci/ll/2.1/rev_ll/a.exe 
[New Thread 7076.0x358]
[New Thread 7076.0xc58]
[New Thread 7076.0x14fc]
[New Thread 7076.0xecc]
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 58
At line 61
At line 163
i:8
j:7
At line 168
At line 58
At line 61
i:7
j:6
At line 174
At line 168
[New Thread 7076.0xcac]
[Thread 7076.0xecc exited with code 0]

Thread 1 "a" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0x60006c170) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:147
147       _M_release() noexcept
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 7076] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Not able to ascertain why the loop execution suspends at the point it does, from the above debug information. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Is the code you show truly a [mcve]? Is that the most minimal code needed to replicate the problem? When in the debugger, have you tried to step through the code?

Comment: yes, but I presume I have a clue about the cause of the error. I just realized that the issue relates to how the list is rearranged inside reverse() method which breaks the logic inside the size() method.

Comment: I would assume there's more problem with the `operator[]` use in the function. You modify the links, and the `operator[]` uses those links. You might want to consider using some other way to reverse the list. Personally I recommend that you look at the list as a kind of stack, and to reverse a stack you "pop" the nodes from the head, adding to a new (temporary, raw) list, then just set the head to the head of the new (temporary) list.

Comment: yes, but the program aims to reverse the list in place without a temporary

Comment: I am thinking overloading the operator[] specifically for reverse() operation should work.

Comment: The only extra data for my suggestion is a pointer to the head of the new list, if that's what you're worried about. If you really want to do it in-place then I suggest you use a double-linked list with pointers to both head and tail, and iterate over the list using the pointers (and not the index operator).